# Failing to compile explicitly specialized template struct on g++/clang++ with std::enable_if

Tags: c++, type-traits, enable-if

I've tried to compile this with msvc and it compiles fine. On the other hand I failed to compile it with g++ and clang++. Error I get is `no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’`. How would I resolve this error?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool v>
struct a {

    template <typename T = typename std::enable_if<v>::type>
    void function();

};

template struct a<false>;
template struct a<true>;

template<bool v>
template<typename T>
void a<v>::function() { }

int main() {

}
```

I'm trying to make `void function` visible if passed `bool` template is `true`.

Comment: You are not using SFINAE correctly because `v` is not dependent on the `function` template parameters. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make `void function` visible if passed bool template is true.

Comment: so `template <bool C = v> std::enable_if_t<C> function ();` or `template <bool C = v, typename = std::enable_if_t<C>> void function ();`, if you prefer.

Comment: Just do an explicit specialization. `template <bool v> struct a { void function(); }; template<> struct a<false> {};`

Comment: @max66 You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using SFINAE correctly because the `bool` you pass to `enable_if` (which is `v`) is not dependent on the function template parameters.

The canonical way to selectively add or remove members of a class template is to use template specialization. For example:

```
template <bool v>
struct a {
    void function();
};

template< >
struct a<false> {
};
```

Now, only `a<true>` will have the `function` member. If you have many common members that should be present in `a` regardless of `v`, you can move these members to a base class and derive both specializations from it:

```
struct a_common {
    void common_function();
};

template <bool v>
struct a : public a_common {
    void function();
};

template< >
struct a<false> : public a_common {
};
```

This can be achieved with SFINAE as well, but it will require a bit of a trick. As mentioned above, we need to make `function` a template, and we need to ensure that the condition used in `enable_if` depends on its template parameters. Since we don't have any template parameters, we need to add a dummy one:

```
template <bool v>
struct a {
    template<
        typename Dummy = void,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same< Dummy, Dummy >::value && v
        >::type
    >
    void function();
};
```

Here, we use `is_same` trait to introduce a formal dependency on the `Dummy` template parameter when calculating the first template parameter of `enable_if`. Naturally, the result of `is_same` will be `true`, so effectively `v` decides whether the `function` template can be instantiated.